# Using awk(or sed) to replace specific group

Tags: awk, sed

For example, if I want to change 424, or any number, to 1 from below string.

```
<revision>424</revison>
```

I usually do this `sed -i 's|<revision>.*</revision>|<revision>777</revision>|g` and it works.

But I have to do a lot of similar commands
and I want to know if I can group like `<revision>(.*)</revision>` and replace only `\1` to `777`. How do I do this?

Comment: You can do: `sed -E 's~<(revision)>[0-9]*</\1>~<\1>777</\1>~g'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU `awk` and with your shown samples, please try following `awk` program. Simple explanation would be, using `match` function of `awk` and creating 4 capturing groups in it, where 1st group captures `<revision>`, 2nd one captures all Digits, 3rd one captures `<\/revison>` and 4th one(if there are any other values) everything. If this match function is true then printing 1st element of arr followed by `newVal`(awk variable which contains new value) followed by 3rd and 4th element value of arr.

```
awk -v newVal="777" '
match($0,/(<revision>)([0-9]+)(<\/revison>)(.*)/,arr){
  print arr[1] newVal arr[3] arr[4]
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `gnu-sed` you can use back-reference of a captured group in pattern matching like:

```sh
s='<revision>424</revision>'

sed -E 's~<(revision)>[0-9]*</\1>~<\1>777</\1>~g' <<< "$s"
<revision>777</revision>
```

However if you want to give `perl` a chance then you can even shorten it further with the use of [look around assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```sh
perl -pe 's~(?<=<(revision)>)\d*(?=</\1>)~777~g' <<< "$s"
<revision>777</revision>
```